# capture keystrokes (special keys [KEYCODE_BUTTON_L1 ..] on zebra handheld barcode scanner with delphi fmx (android) application

Tags: android, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

i need catch special keys (KEYCODE_BUTTON_L1,KEYCODE_BUTTON_R1 ..) on zebra handheld barcode scanner with delphi fmx (android) application.i use  delphi 10.4.2 .
but onkeydown not working.
onkeyup return 0.

can someone help?

thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

thanks all.

its :

`procedure TForm1.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);  begin if TJKeyCharacterMap.JavaClass.deviceHasKey(AKEYCODE_BUTTON_L1) or TJKeyCharacterMap.JavaClass.deviceHasKey(AKEYCODE_BUTTON_R1) then begin barkodoku; end; end;`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).